# Debugging RPC Authentication Error from showmount

Tags: 16.04, nfs, plex, rpc

I have an NFS server which exposes a couple of shares to the local network. It's been up and running for nearly the last year, and I've been using it just about every other day. Today, however, I attempted to mount my share to my laptop after work, and I got 'Permission denied'. I checked my /etc/exports and /etc/hosts.allow, and did a system restart. After rebooting, attempting `showmount -e localhost` returns clnt_create: RPC: Authentication Error (it did not do this before the system restart). Stopping rpcbind returns with 0, but then a subsequent start fails, `journalctl` listing "another instance is already running." Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with how RPC is configured, so any guidance on how to further debug this issue would be very helpful.

Kernel version: 4.4.0-131-generic

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Recent changes to system:

1. Installed Plex media server
2. Updated Python to Python3.6 using apt `debian testing main` pkg
3. Ran a successful `apt-get update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `debian testing main` package updated or installed another package which conflicted with RPC in some way or another. I fixed the problem by removing the package from my `sources.list`, then `apt-get update && apt-get autoremove`. Unfortunately, I don't have any more information about what was causing the error; in hindsight, I guess that's why it's the "testing" package.